# How to efficiently count the number of larger elements for every elements in another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, count

I have the following `df`

```
    name        created_utc
0   t1_cqug90j  1430438400
1   t1_cqug90k  1430438400
2   t1_cqug90z  1430438400
3   t1_cqug91c  1430438401
4   t1_cqug91e  1430438401
... ...         ...
```

in which all values in column `name` are unique. I would like to create a dictionary whose keys are the same elements as in column `name`. The value for each such a key is the number of elements in column `created_utc` greater than that of the key. My expected result is something like

```
{'t1_cqug90j': 6, 't1_cqug90k': 0, 't1_cqug90z': 3, ...}
```

In this case, there are 6 elements in column `created_utc` greater than 1430438400, which is the corresponding value of `t1_cqug90j`. I can do the loop to generate such dictionary. However, the loop is not efficient in my case with more than 3 millions rows.

Could you please elaborate on a more efficient way?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/WebMining/main/df1.csv', header = 0)[['name', 'created_utc']]
df
```

Comment: Hint: Try sorting both columns using the second column as key.

Comment: Broadcasting will work but might be problematic in terms of memory

Comment: Are the names unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible approach. Let's first assume that your `name` column is unique-valued. Then we can count the `created_utc` like this:

```
count_utc = df.groupby('created_utc').size()
cumulative_counts = count_utc.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()

output = dict(zip(df['name'], df['created_utc'].map(cumulative_counts)) )
```

Then the first few output would look like this:

```
{'t1_cqug90j': 0,
 't1_cqug90k': 0,
 't1_cqug90z': 0,
 't1_cqug91c': 3,
 't1_cqug91e': 3,
 't1_cqug920': 5
 ...
}
```

Now if the `name`'s are not unique (which is unlikely due to your output expectation), but in which case, we can certainly just take the largest values of the `cumulative_counts` substract the size of the `name` count (?), something like this:

```
output = dict(zip(df['name'],
                  df['created_utc'].map(cumulative_counts)
                      .sub(df.groupby('name')['name'].transform('size'))
                      .add(1)                  
                 ) )
```

Comment: You may have to add `.sort_index(ascending=False)` in first line for `count_utc` to ensure that cumulative sum is calculated correctly

Comment: @ArjunAriyil yes you could do that. However groupby sort the key increasingly by default.

Comment: Yes. But if I understand correctly, we need to sort the key decreasing as the values are supposed to be the count of dates greater than the given date.

Comment: @ArjunAriyil that's what I'm trying to say, you don't need `sort_index` **because** the key is [**sorted by `groupby` by default**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). So `count_utc` is **sorted by index** with just that command.

Comment: The `name'`s are actually unique. Your solution works perfectly well. Can you elaborate on a modification in which  the value for each such a key is the number of elements in column `created_utc` **less** than that of the key?

Comment: Please have a look at my newly created question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66635000/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-smaller-elements-for-every-elements-in-an).