# How to efficiently count the number of smaller elements for every element in another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, count

I have the following `df`

```
    name        created_utc
0   t1_cqug90j  1430438400
1   t1_cqug90k  1430438400
2   t1_cqug90z  1430438400
3   t1_cqug91c  1430438401
4   t1_cqug91e  1430438401
... ...         ...
```

in which column `name` contains only unique values. I would like to create a dictionary whose keys are the same elements as in column `name`. The value for each such a key is the number of elements in column `created_utc` **strictly smaller** than that of the key. My expected result is something like

```
{'t1_cqug90j': 6, 't1_cqug90k': 0, 't1_cqug90z': 3, ...}
```

In this case, there are 6 elements in column `created_utc` **strictly smaller** than 1430438400, which is the corresponding value of `t1_cqug90j`. I can do the loop to generate such dictionary. However, the loop is not efficient in my case with more than 3 millions rows.

Could you please elaborate on a more efficient way?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/WebMining/main/df1.csv', header = 0)[['name', 'created_utc']]
df
```

**Update:** I posted the question [How to efficiently count the number of larger elements for every elements in another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66631399/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-larger-elements-for-every-elements-in-ano) and received a great answer there. However, I'm not able to modify the code into this case. It would be great if there is an efficient code that can be adapted for both cases, i.e. "strictly larger" and "strictly smaller".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `sort_index` for descending sorting for [your previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66631814/2901002):

```
count_utc = df.groupby('created_utc').size().sort_index(ascending=False)
print (count_utc)
created_utc
1430438401    2
1430438400    3
dtype: int64

cumulative_counts = count_utc.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()

output = dict(zip(df['name'], df['created_utc'].map(cumulative_counts)) )

print (output)
{'t1_cqug90j': 2, 't1_cqug90k': 2, 't1_cqug90z': 2, 't1_cqug91c': 0, 't1_cqug91e': 0}
```